# Can't assign ViewController in storyboard in a mixed project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I have a mixed (objc, with some swift) project, where I am unable to assign

`@objc(XYZMyBaseVC) class MyBaseVC: UIViewController { }
@objc(XYZMySubVC1) class MySubVC1: MyBaseVC { }
@objc(XYZMySubVC2) class MySubVC2: MyBaseVC { }`

For some reason I can only assign `XYZMyBaseVC` to a VC in the storyboard when I need `XYZMySubVC1` and `XYZMySubVC2`. If I type it in manually, the class isn't recognized and outlets break.

I have verified that the files are members of the target, and have performed the usual voodoo of clean, delete derived data and restart Xcode.